# Spring jms listener overwrites id header when converting to Message<Object>

Tags: spring-boot, listener, spring-jms

I have a jms message with an attribute named id in the header.

In my listener when this jms message is converted to Message

```
  @JmsListener(id = "cis-listener", destination = "${amiga.service.jms.cis-listener.destination-fqdn}",
  containerFactory = "containerFactoryListener")
  public void receiveMessage(Message<Object> event) throws UnknownMessageException {
  ...
```

this attribute is overwrited with a generated UUID, when the MessageHeaders are instantiated:

```
    protected MessageHeaders(@Nullable Map<String, Object> headers, @Nullable UUID id, @Nullable Long timestamp) {
    this.headers = (headers != null ? new HashMap<>(headers) : new HashMap<>());

    if (id == null) {
        this.headers.put(ID, getIdGenerator().generateId());
    }
    ...
```

Is there some option to rename the id header attribute i receive in the message to keep the value?

I can access to this attribute by changing the object received by the listener, using the javax.jms.Message but i prefer to use the spring-jms Message implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom `JmsHeaderMapper` to the listener adapter.

- set the container factory `autoStartup` to `false`.
- get the container from the `JmdListenerContainerEndpointRegistry` (by id).
- get the message listener from the container and cast it to `AbstractAdaptableMessageListener`.
- set the custom header mapper.
- start the container.

Your mapper should map your external `id` header to something else. `id` is reserved in spring-messaging. It can be a subclass of `SimpleJmsHeaderMapper`.

Comment: Hello @gary-russell

Thank you for your response.

When i try to get the container from the JmsListenerContainerEndpointRegistry i allways get a null.

The property listenerContainers in this object is empty. :-(

Comment: You are probably trying too early in the context lifecycle; you need to wait until the context is refreshed.

Comment: Since you are using Boot, you can do it in an ApplicationRunner.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Gary Russell first of all thank you for your responses and your help, it's a very big pleasure to be answered by one of the developers of the part of spring i'm having doubts.

In your solution i don't like to be forced to disable the autoStartup. In our project we don't force the autoStartup but if we need to this property will be ignored because we force the start after the custom header mapper is set. We should to define other property and check its value before the container start. It's a little bit odd to change the meaning of the container autostartup property.

I'm also having doubts about the MessageHeader definition. I consider the Message and MessageHeader classes as wrappers / decorators of the jms Message class. I understand that those two classes are defined to make easier the instantiation and access to message and header properties.
That's why i don't get why the timestamp and id values are overwriten. I think that a wrapper shouldn't add this kind of logic, especially when is not so rare to receive an id attribute in the header of the message. If spring needs an id to work with the message maybe, before the creation, should check if an attribute id exists and use other name instead id, the same with timestamp.
Those two attribute names are reserved by spring but the jms deffinition doesn't disallow its use.

I don't like the solution but i think that we will be forced to change our listener to receive a jms message, even though it's more difficult to instantiate the messages to testing it, I think it is a better option.

Thank you again for your time and your help.